# How return initial value for certain fields in redux-persist-transform-filter

Tags: redux, redux-persist

I use redux-persist-transform-filter because I dont need store to local storage
loading indicator, but when I add it to black list I get undefined instead of initial value.
How solve this problem?

```
const saveSubsetBlacklistFilter = createBlacklistFilter(
    'setupTable',
    ['isDataLoading']
);


const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ['setupTable'],
  transforms: [loadSubsetFilter]
};
```

isDataLoading have true as initial value, and it allow show spinner when page first loaded, but with blacklist I get undefined instead.